# Kernel panic on MacBook air 2010

Tags: hard-drive, startup, kernel-panic

A friend of mine gave me an old MacBook air from 2010. I've never owned any Apple products or anything, so it was more of test laptop than an actual productivity one.

When I first got my hands on it I attempted to make a fresh install of macOS (El Capitan) from the clean copy stored in the drive. A couple of errors later I decide to restart the laptop and then... Kernel panic, endless resets.

I tried pretty much everything there is. I cannot access the drive's utility, nor safe boot the computer. I restarted NVRAM and the only difference it made was that the boot sound is on.

I don't own any other Mac devices, but I still managed to make a bootable with El Capitan to restore the system. [This](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/) is the guide I followed in order to create a bootable from Windows. I used the official El Capitan dmg and a 32GB flash drive. Pressing alt (options) it does give me the prompt for "restoring" the system, but when I attempt to it just resets and still tries to load the same version of macOS.

I can very much see the drive being faulty and/or corrupted and I can certainly spare a few bucks to fix it, but I want to make sure I've done everything there is to fix it. Because I'm not very familiar with the Apple ecosystem I'm at my wits end.

The error I get when starting up:
[image]

The error I get when trying to safe boot the OS, which I believe it's a different one:
[image]

Comment: Can you please embed the screenshots directly in your question?

Comment: What do you mean by *"clean copy stored in the drive"*? My understand is that older El Capitan installation files, which may have be useable in the past, are no long useable today.  Do you have access to any other computers that could be used to make installation media? If so, what type and which operating system?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don't know how to explain it properly, it would appear that Mac Os reserves a partition inside the SSD with a fresh clean copy of the OS, an original installation. My first option was to restore that copy. I tried making a bootable from my computer (Win 10) from a guide I found online, using the TransMac utility, the official El Capitan dmg and a 32GB flash drive. But I'm sensing that it's not a proper bootable since it doesn't really show how to recover from the USB. I currently do not have access to any other computer that runs Mac Os.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the guide you found online. I believe Lion and Mountain Lion had that capability. However, the versions of OS X and macOS since Mountain Lion normally do *not* have a partition inside the SSD with a fresh clean copy of the OS. If you had El Capitan installed, then there should have been a recovery partition which is suppose contain software that can reinstall El Capitan by downloading El Capitan from the internet to the partition where installation is to take place. Note that Apple may no longer support that method installation.

Comment: @DavidAnderson [This](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/) is the guide I followed in order to create a bootable from Windows. As for the partition, yeah that sounds about right, since the comment below pointed out it would seem I'm getting the kernel panic out of trying to reinstall from a recovery partition. That's why I tried to make a bootable usb, but... The USB never really shows up.

Comment: Your Mac originally could not use the [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) feature. However, Apple provided [firmware updates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313) to add this feature to your Mac. (I have no idea if your Mac has these updates.) This would allow you to use the Shift-Option-Command-R key combination at startup. I believe the Option-Command-R key combination first required Sierra or newer to be installed. Note that even if your Mac can use OS X Internet Recovery, Apple's servers may not support a model as old as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the instruction posted in the OP's linked [article](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/).  I consider the official official El Capitan dmg to be the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file that can be downloaded from a link posted at the Apple website [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). I installed Windows 10 20H2 in a VirtualBox virtual machine, then installed [Transmac v14.4](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm). Basically, the OP's linked [article](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/) instructions the user to select "Restore with Disk Image" from the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file to a USB flash drive, as shown below.

[image]

I did this using a 16 GB virtual external USB drive. Next, I created an El Capitan virtual machine and tried booting from this virtual external USB drive. I found the drive was not bootable. Therefore, I believe the flash drive created by the OP would not appear in Mac Startup Manager on the OP's Mac when the <kbd>option</kbd> was held down at startup. The OP must have been selecting to boot from the internal drive which probably has been corrupted.

I would like to think the best and assume the [article](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/) was not meant to be misleading. I assume referenced dmg file is not officially from Apple and probably would have worked. However, the [article](https://www.geekrar.com/create-bootable-usb-installer-for-mac-osx-el-capitan-on-windows/) failed to include a link to this file.

Comment: Wow thank you so much you really went above and beyond to save this little guy. Reading your comment you gave me the idea to create a VM for Mac OSX so I did (which was in on itself a quite tricky experience). Once I had the VM running I created a new bootable and lo and behold, it worked fine. I managed to erase the drive and cleanly install the OS. So I now have a fully functional MacBook Air :)

Comment: I thought of your solution before you posted your comment. I suppose I could have posted such as an answer. However, any question or answer referencing running Apple software on non-Apple hardware is not allowed here at Ask Different. If I had posted your answer, the post probably would have been deleted. I am glad you found the solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some hardware issue causing incorrect reads from the filesystem leading to this crash.

I would first try to restore (or update) the operating system using [Cmd+R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255), if this doesn't work the HD might be faulty and needs to be replaced.

Comment: It was my first thought as well so I opened the laptop up and cleaned it because it was fairly dusty. Removed and scree the drive back in and all connections seem to be operational and at first glance, no components of the drive seem faulty.

Also Cmd+R does nothing. It stalls the boot for a while and then proceeds to try booting again and offering me the same kernel panic.

Comment: @Naiada If the drive is "broken" you won't see this.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the kernel is unable to start `launchd`, which is the master userspace process that's responsible for starting every other system and user process. It's a significant failure. In your case you see two different failure codes:

- When you boot from the Recovery partition in order to attempt a reinstall, you see error code `5`, which is an **I/O error**.
- When you boot from the preexisting install of macOS, you see error code `2`, which is a **file not found** error.

Both of these errors strongly suggest a **corrupted filesystem**, at minimum.

Therefore, my first step would be to try booting from a known-good ***external*** installer image. You will need temporary access to another Mac to do this. It will require downloading and unpacking the macOS installer onto an external drive, such as a USB flash drive. Follow the **[official instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)** here.

Once you've flashed the external drive, follow these steps:

1. Attach the newly-flashed external drive to your Mac.
2. Reboot while holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key to enter the Boot Picker.
3. Choose your external drive and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
4. From the macOS Recovery screen, do a full erase of the internal SSD.
5. Install macOS.
6. Hopefully, if there's no (significant) hardware damage to the SSD, the install will complete successfully. At that point, I would want you to take two extra steps:
7. Reboot into **[Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)** (hold <kbd>D</kbd> during boot) to give the machine a cursory hardware check.
8. Reboot into **[Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac)** (hold <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during boot) and run Disk Utility's "Verify Disk" tool on your freshly installed macOS.